# NodeJS : KafkaJSProtocolError: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, kafkajs

I am trying to capture data from Kafka using MongoDB debezium connector but I am getting error when I try to read it with KafkaJS:

```
KafkaJSProtocolError: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members
```

I am using docker images to capture data.

Here are the steps, I am following :

1. Start Zookeeper

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:latest
   ```
2. start kafka

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:latest
   ```
3. I have MongoDB running with replicate mode already
4. Start debezium Kafka connect

   ```
   docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka  debezium/connect:latest
   ```
5. Then Post MongoDB connector configuration

   ```
   curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "mongodb-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector", "mongodb.hosts": "rs0/abc.com:27017", "mongodb.name": "fullfillment", "collection.whitelist": "mongodev.test", "mongodb.user": "kafka", "mongodb.password": "kafka01" } }'
   ```
6. With this If I run a watcher docker container, I am able to data in Json format in console

   ```
   docker run -it --name watchermongo --rm --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka:0.9 watch-topic -a -k fullfillment.mongodev.test
   ```

but I want to capture this data in application so that I can manipulate it, process it and push to ElasticSearch. For that I am using

```
https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs
```

But When I run the consumer code, I am getting error.. Here is code example

```
//'use strict';






// clientId=connect-1, groupId=1

const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')



const kafka = new Kafka({

  clientId: 'connect-1',

  brokers: ['localhost:9092', 'localhost:9093']

})


// Consuming

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: '1' })



var consumeMessage = async () => {



await consumer.connect()

await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'fullfillment.mongodev.test' })



await consumer.run({

  eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {

    console.log({

      value: message.value.toString(),

    })

  },

})



}



consumeMessage();


KafkaJSProtocolError: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members
```

Comment: What consumer code are you running? The fact that you get data from `watch-topic` shows that the Debezium/Kafka bit is working just fine. The error that you've got comes from KafkaJS and how you're using that.

Comment: Also, for writing to Elasticsearch using Kafka Connect with `kafka-connect-elasticsearch`. Hook that up to a Kafka topic to which you write your processed data (or directly to the topic from Debezium, if you just want to mirror MongoDB to Elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks @RobinMoffatt , I have updated code for consuming data using Nodejs app. I tried other kafka-connect-elasticsearch as well , but I am not able to install it on my VM

Comment: Can you try varying `groupId: '1'` for `groupId: 'foobar'`? That error message suggests there are other consumers in a group of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using the same groupId in both Connect and your KafkaJS consumer. If you do, they will be part of the same consumer group, which means that messages would only be consumed by one or the other, if it even worked at all.

If you change the groupId of your KafkaJS consumer to something unique, it should work.

Note that by default a new KafkaJS consumer group will start consuming from the latest offset, so it won't consume already produced messages. You can override this behavior with the `fromBeginning` flag in the `consumer.subscribe` call. See https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#from-beginning

Comment: So that means even though from Zookeeper, kafka docker images .. i didn't pass any client id or group id.. while consuming it.. I can use any random client id and group id ?

Comment: Thanks @tommy for your help.. I just changed group Id from 1 to 2 and I am able to see data in console through this NodeJS app...Thanks a lot... Any suggestion how to sink this data in ElasticSearch... So custom node app to do this dirty work